# autofill table with data from another table

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So this may be a little confusing, I have two csv's that are entered into two different tables. One goes into the `Event` table. And the other goes into the `Via` table.

Now, The First one populates the name date and time of the event. This exists in the `Event` table.

Now the second one has the date and time in the same cell (The name is kinda the same.)

Now i want to have the column in the `Event` table to be populated with the link that exists in the `via` table.

How do i go about doing this?

the rake task i have to populate the first table is here (i'm guessing it'd be in the same rake task?)

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'csv'
namespace :event do
   task reload: :environment do
       gzipped = open('')
       csv_text = Zlib::GzipReader.new(gzipped).read
       csv = CSV.parse(csv_text, :headers=>true)
       csv.each do |row|
         Event.find_or_create_by(time: row[9], date: row[10], eventname: row[7])

       end
   end
end
```

Comment: So do you have a matching foreign key for the `Via` table? Presumably you can load the second CSV, then each row `Event.find_by(:name, xxx)` or whatever and add that relation

Comment: @PeterMellett Nope i haven't set that up. didn't need it and didn't know if i would for this issue